# How to make a Input fill the remaining space

Tags: html, css, web

In this case I have the `li.first` which fills a entire line (100%) and the `li.third` that will have a variable size depending on the text (Return from a external service).

I need to make the `li.second` to fill a line alongside with the `li.third`. In the `li.second` I have an `input` that have to fill the entire line LESS the space ocuped by the link contained in the `li.third`.

I have found some ways to do that, but I would need to change my HTML code and in this case I can't.

Is there a way to do that without changing the HTML, just with CSS?

```
 <ul>
        <li class="first">Some Random Text</li>
        <li class="second">
            <input type="text" />
        </li>
        <li class="third">
            <a href="#">Some Random Text (that will change time to time)</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set you `li` elements to `display:inline-block` and float them:

```
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
```

Don't forget to clear the float:

```
ul:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but in this case I have to ensure that the input will fill the remaining space.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't add any external API

Comment: flexbox is not an external API.  Just a new CSS display mode for element layout. Supported in lots of browsers, but with plenty of prefixing to make it work.  Browser support: http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox